# How do I calculate the voltage in this circuit?

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis, current-source

I have the following circuit:

[image]

I am a beginner at this stuff, so... ;)

Ok, the question is to calculate the voltage across the terminals A and B? I have no clue how to do that? You can't just take together some of the resistors. The Node method seems a little overkill (only based on the small amount of elements).

Question: What is the voltage across the terminals A and B?

P.S. The weird box (for some) in the top is a current source.

Comment: Current between?  Voltage across & current through.

Comment: Sorry, good point ;) Changed the post

Comment: Are you sure the question is asking what the current through A and B is, not the current through the resistors? As stated, the answer is trivial: zero amps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, lets re-arrange the components to see what's actually happening. As you can see, you have a simple voltage divider:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHqYsX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To get the voltage across A and B, use Ohm's Law:
$$
V = I*R
$$
To find the total R, you first need to find the parallel value of R1 and R2:
$$
R_p = {R1*R2\over R1+R2}
$$
and then
$$
R_t = R_p + R3
$$

Answer (score 0):

R1 and R2 are parallell, so (R1*R2) / (R1+R2) gives you their resistance.

Then add the result with R3 and you have one resistor for the circuit.

Then it's just Ohms law to calculate the current over the one resistor. Voltage / Resistance = Current. Volia!